# Gradle project refresh failed cause : error reading zip file

Tags: java, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working with two projects simultaneously, since yesterday the project is working fine, from today it was showing error like

> Gradle 'FASOService_2.2.2' project refresh failed Error:Cause: error
>   reading zip file

I tried

> *Preferences --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build Tools --> Gradle*

Then check Offline work, and I also tried

> *File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart --> Invalidate and Restart.*

I even tried deleting .gradle inside c/users/----/wrapper/dists/8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

I have two files in the same folder like **gradle-2.14.1-all, gradle-1.10-all**

what actually causes the problem?

these stackoverflow references not worked for me [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452521/android-studio-gradle-error-reading-zip-file/33270341#33270341), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file)

Comment: gradle may not have permission to read that zip file.

Comment: it was working fine till yesterday, if so how to check it?